# Conferindo se login já existe via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Tudo bem?
Estou querendo que ao perder o foco, o campo de login vá até o banco e procure por um login igual. Se houver, quer dizer que o cara tem que usar outro e pra isso o retorno deve ser um erro. Se não houver um login como o dele, nada acontece e ele continua a se cadastrar à vontade.

Meu código js é:

```
function checalogin() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax-insere.php?login=' + $('input[name=login]').val(),
        type: 'GET',
        });
}
```

E o código php é:

```
    if(isset($_GET['login']) && ($_GET['login'] != '')) {
    $txtLogin = $_GET['login'];    
    $checa_login = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login LIKE "' . $txtLogin . '"';
    //echo $checa_login;
    $resposta = mysql_query($checa_login) or die(mysql_error());
    $value = mysql_fetch_assoc($resposta);
    if ($value['login'] == $txtLogin) { 
        header('Location:visualiza.php?loginExiste=1');        
    }
}
```

Vejam que o header devolve com loginExiste=1. Eu criei uma condição no php que:

```
if(isset($_GET['loginExiste']) && $_GET['loginExiste'] == 1) {
   echo '<script>'.
       'Materialize.toast('Já existe um login igual a esse. Tente algodiferente.', 7000);'.
   '</script>';
}
```

Porém, ao perder o foco, ou seja, onBlur, nada acontece. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está misturando PHP com Javascript de uma maneira "errada". Não está errado, mas o que espera como resultado é diferente do que realmente irá ocorrer.

O `location` apenas irá afetar o AJAX, mas não irá acionar o PHP, por motivos óbvios (o PHP não é executado no navegador do cliente).

Portanto, o que de fato está ocorrendo é:

```
AJAX -> ajax-insere.php?login=nome -> visualiza.php?loginExiste=1
```

O PHP que existe em visualiza.php não tem impacto na página, isso apenas irá ser o retorno do AJAX, então você deve tratar tal retorno. Portanto é o AJAX quem recebe o `<script>'Materialize.toast('Já existe um login igual a esse. Tente algodiferente.', 7000);</script>`. *Uma solução é o `.html()`, dessa forma irá injetar na página o `script`, mas não acho uma solução tão eficaz.*

**Melhor correção:**

Javascript:

```
function checalogin() {
  $.getJSON('ajax-insere.php?login=' + $('input[name=login]').val(), function(json) {

    if (json['isValid'] === false) {
      Materialize.toast('Já existe um login igual a esse. Tente algo diferente.', 7000);
    }

  });

}
```

> Dessa forma o alerta/toast irá ser exibido pelo proprio AJAX, com um retorno de true/false do JSON.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['login']) && !empty($_GET['login'])){

    $resposta = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE login = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['login']) . '"');
    $json['isValid'] = mysql_num_rows($resposta) > 0 ? false : true;

    echo json_encode($json);

}
```

> Dessa maneira o PHP irá retornar true/false se já houver um nome IGUAL ao digitado pelo usuário.

**ATENÇÃO:**

O mysql_* já é obsoleto (novas versões não suportam mais isto!) e não é recomendado utilizar!

Comment: Cara, entendi perfeitamente onde eu estava errando, ou melhor, confundindo. Fiz as alterações e até alterei um pouco mas ainda estou tendo problemas.
O json SEMPRE retorna {"isValid":true}. Tentei dar um echo na query e ela não aparece. A variável $_GET['login'] vem. Mas acho que não está rolando a query... você também não acha?

Comment: Talvez seja necessário alterar algumas coisas. :S Tente separar, como vez anteriormente, a query do `mysql_query` em então dê o echo. Assim teste no PHPMyAdmin (ou qualquer gerenciador de MySQL). Não sei se foi isto que fez. O PHP irá retornar `true` se não houver dados que se enquadrem em `login = $_GET['login']`, antes você utilizava o `LIKE`, o que é diferente! Experimente remover o `mysql_real_escape_string`. Você pode também criar um `$json['Error'] = !$resposta;` isso irá retornar `"Error":true` se o `mysql_query` não for executado.

Comment: SHOW, Funcionou. Separei a query e atribui a uma variável o valor de **mysql_real_escape_string** . Nem precisei mexer no JS.
Valeu mesmo bro!

Answer (score 0):

já tentou casar essa ação do blur usando jQuery?

```
$("#IdDoCampoQueVaiDarBlur").blur( function(){
    checalogin();
});
```